# First android app - Cannot find item from resource

Tags: android

So I am following the documentation for creating a first app from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). and this is what I have so far nothing complicated

```
import static android.R.attr.id;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and my other activity is

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I have this causing the problem

```
   EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

and the problem is android studio says that

```
Error:(25, 55) error: int cannot be dereferenced
```

I am not sure what `R.id.edit_message` is and where it should be placed ? In my resources i do not have anything called `edit_message` any suggestions on how I can fix this issue ? 
this is what my activity_main.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.test.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should should change the TextView in your layout to EditText

That is change

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

to

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

You complete layout will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.test.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because in your activity_main.xml, you are trying to reference an `EditText` that is not there yet. Add the code below into your `activity_main.xml`

```
<EditText
    android:id="+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The code below which is in your `MainActivity.java` is basically creating a connection between the `EditText` in your xml to the java.

`EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give an id to all your widgets in your xml code with the id property. 
Format to do that is:
android:id="@+id/myId"
and then you can access any element by using its id in your Java code 
EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.myId);

PS: You also seem to be accessing a EditText which is not present in your layout file.